# Access enum from Class object

Tags: c#, class, object, enums

I am trying to develop a class that I can use to create table/columns in SQLite dynamically; I have created my class as follow:

```
public class NewColumns
{
    public string ClmName;

    public Types NewType { get; set; }

    public void SetName(string NewColumn)
    {
        ClmName = NewColumn;
    }
}

public enum Types
{
    INTEGER = 0,
    REAL = 1,
    NUMERIC = 2,
    TEXT = 3,
    BLOB = 4,
}

public static bool CreateTable(string DBPath, string TableName, params NewColumns ClumnName)
{
    bool succ = false;
    mDBcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + DBPath + ".db3";
    mDBcon.Open();
    cmd = new SQLiteCommand(mDBcon);
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TableName + " (ISBN VARCHAR(15), Tag VARCHAR(15));";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return succ;
}
```

I would like to pass my new values to the class like this:

```
clsSqlite.CreateTable("test", "newTable", new clsSqlite.NewColumns { ClmName = "", NewType.INTEGER });
```

But the “NewType” on the code above not recognising my enum Values and its give me the following error if I type the enum value ‘INTEGER’ manually:

Invalid initializer member declaratory

Thanks in advance for the help.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
clsSqlite.CreateTable(
    "test", 
    "newTable", 
    new clsSqlite.NewColumns { ClmName = "", NewType = Types.INTEGER });
```

`NewType` is the name of your property, the enum is called `Types`

Comment: perfect, my silly mistake, all works fine know. thanks. I have one more equation and i would appreciate if you help me on this too, to retrieve enume value I use this method : enumValue.ToString(), it works fine but is it safe or I should use diffident method?

Comment: i think that's ok.. But this doesn't return the *value* of the enum but its *name*

Answer (score 0):

move the enums outside the class definition and you will be fine.

You may consider using another name than Types for your enum, as it will probably confuse you and others in the future.

And also change your variable into a property.

Comment: thanks for the advise, its all works fine, and i have also changed the name of type.